# To have efficient sorting in mongo is it necessary to change the _id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a document with only about 200 elements in it.  But I am still getting a very slow response just by querying it like:

```
Product.order_by([:name, :asc]).limit(20)
```

I do have an index on name which I have verified exists in the mongo shell.  Is the only way to return efficiently sorted results to change they _id value to something like

```
"#{name}_#{random_id}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: absolutely not. 
Long answer: let's make sure the query is using your index (not just that the index exists).

Our query:

This does not use an index (in this case, because it does not exist)

```
db.products.find().sort( { name: -1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 1042,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1042,
    "n" : 1042,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "millis" : 5,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        }
```

Let's prove it

```
db.products.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "project_development.products",
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

Create the index

```
db.products.ensureIndex({name:1});
```

Now when we explain the query:

```
db.products.find().sort( { name: -1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name reverse",
    "nscanned" : 1042,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1042,
    "n" : 1042,
    "millis" : 2,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "name" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was referring to products as product before and it didn't complain.